# How this 'for' loop for reverse stack affecting front stack?(Balanced brackets problem using stacks)

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, brackets

I need to separate a sequence of brackets to check whether it is balanced or not . My approach is to divide the sequence into two equal halves and push them into separate stacks.
The problem is  occurring when I try to push the 2nd half of the sequence into reverse stack. It is affecting the first stack . I have no idea why this is happening ,if I remove the 2nd half sequence part of code ,the first stack is working fine. Below is the code and I will also attach the output with and without the effect of 2nd stack.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char front_stack[]={};
char rev_stack[]={};
int topf=0,topr=0;

void push_fr(char);
void push_re(char);

int main()
{
    string seq;
    cin>>seq;

    int len=seq.length();

    for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
        front_stack[i]=seq[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
        cout<<front_stack[i]<<endl;

    for(int i=3,j=0;i<len;i++)
        rev_stack[j]=seq[i];

    for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
        cout<<front_stack[i]<<endl;
}
```

#### **OUTPUT**:

```sh
Sequence --{[()]}
Before adding second stack
First stack's output
{
[
(
After adding to second stack
First stack's output
{
}
(
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your arrays have 0 items in them, so when you do front_stack[0], front_stack[1], ... you're overwriting some other variable.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for responding .But  I am using different stack ,how can I overwrite when I am not using the first stack and why only last two elements are affected int the front stack.Kindly explain, I don't get this .

Comment: @Sumanthmandalapu Use [`std::stack<char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Comment: @user253751    I changed to front_stack[100] and rev_stack[100] as you mentioned and the error is solved .

Comment: Your trimmed-down example (trimming down is good!) no longer makes use of any stack functionality. So it would make sense to re-frame your question without referring to stacks (and maybe gain some insight in the process).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Thank you, but I am learning DS now and trying to implement from scratch .

Comment: @JaMiT I didn't understood what you said . I tried to implement by creating stacks at first using push function but felt its a bit overdo so I directly added to the stack  . Kindly help me where to change the question.

Comment: @Sumanthmandalapu Can you point me to one line in your trimmed-down code where you **use** either a push or a pop function? With neither of those functions, you no longer have a stack. You have two (C-style) arrays with no additional functionality associated with them. *The point is to think more abstractly. Don't be blinded by your goals. See what you actually have (and don't have). When you can no longer justify the name "stack", drop the name "stack" even though your goal is for something to become a stack in your full program.*

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for advice sir, yes you are right I did not use either of the functions in this code. I actually wrote both the push and pop functions in the previous code ,but I removed as you said just to achieve the required functionality using arrays . I will change the code as you advised and implement it . On line 7 you can see the push function I did not remove it in the code, while I removed both push and pop implementations. I will try to develop the abstract thinking , is there anything that I need to remember while learning DS and algos? Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays have 0 items in them, so when you do `front_stack[0]`, `front_stack[1]`, ... you're overwriting some other variable.

If you want to store data in arrays, you need to make them actually have some items in them e.g. `char front_stack[100]`, `char rev_stack[100]`

By the way, you don't need `={}` in this program.